# Distance threshold for clustering

Tags: clustering, k-means, online-algorithms, distance, threshold

Usually online clustering methods (based on kmeans or not) define a distance threshold value. If a new data-point $x$ is far enough from the nearest center $c$ (i.e. the distance from $x$ to $c$ is greater than the threshold), then just give this $x$ its own new cluster.

I saw that many methods theoretically define this sort of threshold as "the mean distance of all data-points to the center of their distribution". That is, let $\bar{x}$ be the center-of-mass of all data-points, the threshold is defined as the mean distance of all data-points to $\bar{x}$.

**Question:** Why is the threshold defined like that ? Does this make any sense ? What is the idea behind setting the threshold to this value (mean of distances to the center-of-mass) ?

Comment: Which "many methods" did you see that in? Any references?

Comment: Same question as Anony-Mousse, which methods describe that? According to what you describe, the threshold is the radius of a ball the encloses all data points. Now, that's a very large ball and I would be surprised if you can re-cluster even the existing points using that threshold.

Comment: @TenaliRaman I'll try to find some references where I saw that later, and update my post. So if you think that this is a large threshold (it is in fact the the case), which thresholds can be more convenient for such a situation ?

Comment: I would be tempted to use something along the lines of $max_i(max_{x \in C_i}(distance(x, c_i)))$ where $c_i$ is the center of cluster $C_i$. 

P.S.[This recent paper in ICML 2012](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/papers/kulis-jordan-icml12.pdf) discusses k-means like algorithm inspired by DPMM (but simple enough like k-means) that can perform just as well as DPMM and enjoys the scalability of k-means. Might be of interest to you.

Comment: My earlier threshold might be a bit too conservative. A slightly bolder threshold could be $\frac{min_{i,j:i \neq j}d(c_i, c_j)}{2}$.

Comment: The above threshold comes from the idea : think of spherical balls surrounding each cluster and allow all of them to expand at equal rates and then continue to expand until one of them clashes with the other. So you see, you can extend this idea in many ways to get probably better estimates of threshold that suit your requirement. For example, you can assume that not all spherical balls expand at the same rate and that the rate is proportional to the number of points in the cluster etc.

Comment: @TenaliRaman why did you said that the distance that I described is "the radius of a ball the encloses all data points" ? Is this its name ? Actually it does not encloses all data points.

Comment: @user995434, you are right, it doesn't enclose all data points. I realized later that you are averaging over all the distances, so it can't enclose all points. My mistake there.